# Result of intersect between two shapefile is empty

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm trying to intersect one shapefile with an other one in QGIS. The problem is, whatever I do, the result is always empty, (the files I'm working on are not empty).

I tried to change the scr, delete the files, change the order, but nothing, the result is always empty. I know it happened to some people, but none of the solution worked for me.

Do you have any idea of what might cause this issue?

I can give you my files, but they are just two basics shapefiles so I don't know if it's very useful.

Comment: are they both in the same projection?

Comment: Yes, i tried in the same projection, and not in the same

Comment: Are the shapefiles in the same projection?

Comment: Yes the shapefiles are in the same projection

Comment: Yes it would be *very* useful if you gave us your shapefiles! And also a fuller description of your workflow (what menu item you are using, what you put in the boxes etc)